# database first - how can I seed database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building application using database first (not code first) - so I have database and then i have generated model in application.

In Global.asax.cs file I have:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //.........
        Database.SetInitializer(new BlogInitializer());
    }
}
```

I have also my own class to seed database:

```
public class BlogInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DatabaseContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        // .....
    }
}
```

**But I have no records in database, debugger never go to method Seed() - why??**

PS. Maybe this is important - I don't have enabled migrations of course - I don't need migrations because I am building my project using database first.

Comment: Can we see your Seed method?

Comment: Try to get something from your context.
Db will be initialized after trying to get data.